# Передача указателя или ссылки в функцию

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

**Есть следующий код:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
void ptr(int *ptr, int d)
{
  *ptr = d;
}
void ref(int &ref, int d)
{
  ref = d;
}
int main(void) {

    int digit = 154;
    int &a = digit;

    ref(a, 999);
    printf("%d - %d\n", digit, a);

    ptr(&a, 1000);
    printf("%d - %d\n", digit, a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Интересует следующее:**

Есть такое понятие как передача по значению, работает ли это понятие когда мы передаем аргумент: как указатель, как ссылку?(Лучше объяснить как и почему)

P.S Мне почему-то кажется что когда мы передаем аргумент как указатель то создается внутренняя переменная (локальная), а значит тратится память и так каждый раз при передаче указателю. С ссылкой пока не ясно.

Answer (score 8):

По сути, **все** варианты - передача по значению.

При `f(T t)` по значению передается объект `t`, для которого создается временная копия.

Очевидно, что при передаче по указателю `f(T* t)` по значению передается указатель `t`, для которого создается временная копия. Памяти тратится ровно столько, сколько занимает указатель.

При передаче по ссылке `f(T&t)` *фактически* происходит передача указателя. Можно рассматривать эту передачу как передачу по указателю, просто указатель в теле функции везде разыменован, так что не приходится писать то-то типа `*t = 5;` - грубо говоря, эту `*` за вас добавляет компилятор. Соответственно, памяти и в этом случае тратится ровно столько, сколько занимает указатель.

Как иллюстрация - https://godbolt.org/g/TSZt1y

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! Но все же я пока не буду принимать ответ вдруг найдутся люди которые смогут что-то еще добавить =)

Comment: Бывают ли такие ситуации когда как аргумент выгоднее обычная переменная а не указатель или ссылка?!

Comment: Конечно. Разыменование - тоже операция, занимающая время. Так что если это небольшой по размеру аргумент, оригинал которого не нужно менять в функции, и к которому в функции частое обращение - то может быть выгоднее передать его по значению. Но такие вещи нужно проверять с помощью профайлера.Компиляторы пошли очень умные, оптимизаторы в ник крутые - так что во что именно превратится ваш код и как быстро он будет работать - заранее сказать невозможно. То, что я написал - это, так сказать, теоретически. Компилятор может вообще не вызывать функцию, а встроить код...

Comment: Вот интересно в вашем примере по ссылке код `return t+1;` интерпретируется как команда `lea`, а если убрать `+1` то как `mov`. Почему так? И мне понятна команда `mov`, но не понятна команда `lea`, для чего она? Насчет дизассемблированного кода для ссылки и для указателя понятно - код идентичен!

Comment: Именно это - идентичность кода для указателя и ссылки - я и хотел показать.

Comment: А насчет команд ассемблера которые я написал выше не в курсе?

Comment: `lea eax, [rdi+1]` - 'load effective address'. Делает она `eax = rdi+1`, заменяет `mov` и `inc`.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас есть функция, объявленная, к примеру, как

```
void f( T parm );
```

где `T` - это некоторый тип, и функция вызывается с некоторым аргументом `arg`, как

```
f( arg );
```

то это можно представить следующим образом

```
void f( /* T parm */ )
{
    T parm = arg;
    //...
}
```

То есть параметры функции - это ее локальные переменные, которые инициализируются аргументами, переданными функции при ее вызове.

Для функций из вашего примера это можно представить следующим образом

Следующее определение функции и ее вызов

```
void ptr(int *ptr, int d)
{
  *ptr = d;
}

// ...

ptr(&a, 1000);
```

можно представить как

```
void ptr( /* int *ptr, int d */ )
{
    int *ptr = &a;
    int d = 1000;

    *ptr = d;
}
```

То есть переменные `ptr` и `d` являются локальными переменными функции, которые после завершения работы функции прекратят свое существование.

То же самое имеет место и для данной функции и ее вызова

```
void ref(int &ref, int d)
{
  ref = d;
}

//...

ref(a, 999);
```

Их можно представить следующим образом

```
void ref(/* int &ref, int d */)
{
    int &ref = a;
    int d = 999;

    ref = d;
}
```

Поэтому если вы хотите изменить исходный аргумент, то соответствующий параметр функции следует объявлять либо как ссылку на тип объекта, передаваемого в качестве аргумента, либо как указатель на тип объекта, передаваемого в качестве аргумента.

Механизм объявления ссылки в качестве параметра функции обычно заключается в том, что выделяется память для ссылки в функции, и ссылка инициализируется аргументом, который в свою очередь передается через указатель на аргумент.

Comment: `который в свою очередь передается через указатель на аргумент.` - тут вот что-то не понял!

Comment: @MaximPro Для своих параметров функции выделяют память. Чтобы можно было обратиться к аргументу по "ссылке", обычно внутренне передается указатель на аргумент.

Comment: то есть вы имели ввиду что внутренний механизм ссылок - указатели? я правильно вас понимаю?

Comment: @MaximPro Да, при работе с параметрами и аргументами, в функциях реализуется передача адреса аргумента, если параметр объявлен как ссылка.

Comment: то есть неявная передача в отличии от указателей так?

Comment: @MaximPro Да, нужен какой-то механизм, который будет указывать на исходный аргумент.

Comment: понятно, спасибо за объяснение!